# How to evaluate N largest elements in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Can numpy evaluate N largest elements in a multidimensional array?
Say:

```
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3]
b=a.max(num_of_max_elements=2) #I know it won't work, and I want it to be 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to sort and then use the last `n` numbers.  This can also be done without changing the original array.  Here's an example how to find the largest 10 numbers in a 10x10 array:

```
a = numpy.random.randint(1000, size=100).reshape(10, 10)
indices = a.ravel().argsort()
print a.ravel()[indices[-10:]]
```

This code prints something like

```
array([909, 917, 926, 936, 952, 960, 961, 964, 969, 993])
```

Comment: That's O(n log n) though compared to O(n log k) (with k being the number items to return) for the obvious implementation (no idea how to get that in numpy though). Also it's O(n) vs. O(k) wrt memory if we may not change the array.

Comment: @Voo: Is using a heap queue what you mean by the "obvious solution"?  There is no heap implementation in NumPy, and Python's `heapq` module will be way slower than the above code even for very large arrays.  Do you have any practical suggestions how to improve this code?

Comment: I should've said the obvious "algorithm" sorry. As I said I don't see any way to implement this efficiently in numpy itself. I assume writing a c extension specific to the problem would work, but doing that well isn't simple. It pretty much depends on the size of n and k how this can help us. If the simple sort solution is good enough, clearly go for that.

Comment: @voo: All this is the reason why I started my answer with "the easiest way to do this…"  The *fastest* way would be a different one.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to point out that theoretically this is less efficient by about a factor of log n than the optimal solution, which I think should be mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

A full sort is unnecessary. You can use [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy-partition) on the negative of your array, slice the first *n* elements, then take the negative to reverse the initial transformation.

If you supply `axis=None`, the array is flattened before sorting.

```
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(1000, size=100).reshape(10, 10)

res = -np.partition(-a, kth=10, axis=None)[:10]
# array([961, 999, 932, 937, 976, 916, 984, 910, 908, 901])
```

Alternatively, you can specify negative `kth`:

```
res = np.partition(a, kth=-10, axis=None)[-10:]
# array([901, 908, 910, 916, 984, 932, 937, 999, 961, 976])
```

No ordering is specified for `np.partition`. The solution takes O(*n*) time in the worst case.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably most efficient to [reverse-sort](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) your array and take the first `N` elements:

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 sorted(a, reverse=True)[:2]
```

If you want to find the largest elements in a multidimensional array, use `a.ravel()` which unrolls down to a single dimension

As written, this doesn't actually use numpy, but you can do something similar with `np.sort`, although you'll have to reverse it yourself, e.g., by indexing with `[::-1]`, giving the rather baroque-looking

```
np.sort(a.ravel())[::-1][:2]
```

Comment: Judging from the title, I think the OP wants to apply this to a multidimensional NumPy array.